# Reading an xml value into a property for Wix

Tags: xml, wix, properties

In my application installer, I want to read credentials for logging into a database from an xml file. Is there any way that I can do this. If I had to use custom actions, how would I assign the return value into the property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a good example: [http://www.dalun.com/wix/05.22.2007.htm](https://web.archive.org/web/20121230235338/http://www.dalun.com/wix/05.22.2007.htm) (**UPDATE**: *Resurrected from WayBack **August 2018***)
They're using VBS code there; if you need C, start with looking at MsiSetProperty (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370391%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: The dalun link appears to be broken

Answer (score 5):

WiX doesn't have a built in Xml read pattern, only Xml write. You'll have to write a custom action to accomplish this.   BTW, VBScript is not a good solution due to ActiveScript hosting problems in Windows Installer.